# Remove "/Public/index.php" from url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, cpanel

I created a mvc painting that works nginx perfectly with this configuration:

```
 location / {
        root   html/Public;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm; 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        location ~ .php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/Public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I need an htaccess for cpanel that removes the /Public/index.php but maintains the integrity of the folders inside Public for example /Template/image/slide.jpg

Comment: `FallbackResource /index.php`

Comment: Not work, error 500

Comment: `sudo a2enmod mod_dir`